# How to select particular tab in target file

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two buttons in a html page, if I click on the first button I want to select the first tab in the target html file. If I click on the second button, I want to select the second tab of the target html file.

Is it possible? I have heard of `ui-sref-active` but I don't see how I can apply it in my case.

In my home.html page I have :

```
<div class="col-md-1">
    <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" ui-sref="tab1"></button><br>Tab1
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
    <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" ui-sref="tab2"></button><br>Tab2
</div>
```

ui-router :

```
.state('tab1', {
    parent: 'entity',
    url: '/tabs',
    views: {
        'content@': {
        templateUrl: 'app/entities/tabs.html',
        controller: 'TabsController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
        }
    },
    resolve: {
    }
})

.state('tab2', {
    parent: 'entity',
    url: '/tabs',
    views: {
        'content@': {
        templateUrl: 'app/entities/tabs.html',
        controller: 'TabsController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
        }
    },
    resolve: {
    }
})
```

tabs.html :

```
<uib-tabset active="activeForm" id="rapportAlerteForm">
    <uib-tab
        index="0" heading="Tab1">
    </uib-tab> 
    <uib-tab
        index="1" heading="Tab2">
    </uib-tab> 
</uib-tabset>
```

Comment: go through https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/aWqli3

Comment: thanks; in this exemple clicking on Route1 or Route2 doesn't activate one of the two tabs (R1 items and R2 items2 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the plunkr if it is of help to you -
https://plnkr.co/edit/xq0DyenMHwPse4CO9KJO?p=preview

```
<p><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="active = 1">Select second tab</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="active = 2">Select third tab</button>  </p>
```

Comment: Good answer. Additionally you could __explain how it works__: the *scope variable* `active` is used within directive `uib-tabset` to activate the tab by index. It would be good style to use the (prepared) function `setActiveTab` in button's `ng-click`.